nginx server failing after a certain number of new connections or refreshes
I am having this issue where I am using nginx on a Ubuntu VM to host a very basic website. the website is so basic that it literally only hosts a single picture and a single button.
Whenever I sudo systemctl restart nginx this appears to "fix" the issue for a while. But when re-testing the website on my phone(s) and my desktop with a few refreshes to simulate light and normal use. Eventually the webpages take extremely long to respond and they get the "cannot reach server" errors.
Here is my config file: I have developed this config file through hours of digging through the Internet and jumbling together suggestions. I have a feeling like this is a super simple fix that I am overlooking, because, according to the web, nginx is supposed to handle thousands of connections all at once with no problems. I am running the server with 4GB ram and 3 cores on a i7 10750. Please help. Please see config file for my attempt to remedy the issue, but like I was saying with time or after some number of new connections and refreshes it becomes unbearably slow and can't connect to the server after a certain point anymore.
EDIT: tailing the error log file doesn't produce any errors, and the other log file eventually when it website loads just outputs the expected output.
EDIT2: further digging I see that requesting the SSL is what takes unbearably long. Typically after a fresh server reset it takes a fraction of a second to run this command: curl -w "\nSSL Handshake Time: %{time_appconnect}\nTotal Time: %{time_total}\n" -o /dev/null -s https://directinghomesolutions.com
However trying to do it repeatedly I will get mixed results from 8+ seconds all the way up to 100 at some points. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get this down?
EDIT 3: I figured it out, I needed to go out and buy a network adapter for my computer that I then allowed the VM to directly use through the USB port. Afterwards I setup proper port forwarding for ports 80 and 443 through my router, if you are running into the same issues with your router be sure to also double check your SSL certificates installation etc. Turns out it nothing (or nearly nothing) to do with NGINX.

I figured it out, I needed to go out and buy a network adapter for my computer that I then allowed the VM to directly use through the USB port. Afterwards I setup proper port forwarding for ports 80 and 443 through my router, if you are running into the same issues with your router be sure to also double check your SSL certificates installation etc. Turns out it nothing (or nearly nothing) to do with NGINX.
